Root certificate is not trusted by the trust provider
After running
code tunnel

I got this:
2024-09-15 12:33:06.942 [info] [2024-09-15 12:33:06] error failed to lookup tunnel: connection error: error sending request for url (https://asse.rel.tunnels.api.visualstudio.com/tunnels/fancy-chair-2b20skz?includePorts=true&tokenScopes=host&api-version=2023-09-27-preview): error trying to connect: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider. (os error -2146762487)

I tried to import certificate as in The solution for .NET installation, but it does not work.
Version: 1.93.1 (user setup)
Commit: 38c31bc77e0dd6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40
Date: 2024-09-11T17:20:05.685Z
Electron: 30.4.0
ElectronBuildId: 10073054
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
Node.js: 20.15.1
V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631
I want to make VScode tunnel work.
